# How implements "New Factorization Method"

Tags: factoring

just i trying to implements the NF(New Factorization) method published on the [paper](http://www.ijcsi.org/papers/IJCSI-8-6-1-242-247.pdf)

```
Example 4:
Let N=21
S=5
P=gcd(24,21)=3>1
Q=21/3=7
P and Q is factor of N.
```

NF method as follows:
1. Let any positive integer is N.
2. Compute the square root of N.
3. Take ceiling function of step two.
4. Decrement by one in square of step three.
5. Compute  the  greatest  Common  divisor of step three and step number one.
6. If step five is grater than one.
7. Step five is a factor of step one.
8. Compute other factor of N divided by step seven.
9. Otherwise  increment  the  value  of steps  three by one and continues step three to eight, till step four is grater than one.

but i not understand how i can get the "24" ?

```
long n = 21;
long s = (long) (Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(n)));
long p = gcd(24, n);
if(p>1){
        long q = n/p;
        boolean success = (q*p==n);
        if(success) System.out.println("P: " + p + " Q: " + q);
}
```

## Solution

```
long n = 21;//999962000357L
long s = (long) (Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(n)));
long p;
long b;
while(true){
    b = s*s-1;
    p = gcd(n, b);
    s = s+1;
    if(p != 1) break;
}
if(p>1){
    long q = n/p;
    boolean success = (q*p==n);
    if(success) System.out.println("P: " + p + " Q: " + q);
}
```

## More thanks for all.

Comment: According to the convoluted description of "step 4", the 24 in the code should be replaced with $s\cdot s-1$, -- After skimming over the paper, I dare ask if the Journal actually does employ peer review and if none of the reviewers complained about the poor language ...

Comment: thanks, really i crazy trying to understand that.

Comment: The condition "till step 4 is greater than 1" is of course nonsense.

Comment: Step four is step three squared minus one, i.e. ceiling of step two squared minus one, i.e. ceiling of the square root of N squared minus one. $\lceil\sqrt{24}\rceil^2-1$.

Comment: thanks, just i testing, yours show me, ways to fix that.

Comment: What does Step 4 mean in English?

Comment: thanks guys the method works, but need check on both directions, bottom, and top to get the p*q, just i do an test with an RSA 16bit key and works https://twitter.com/JhetoX/status/806666900730220544 well to make an effective "RSA Public Key reverser", is need implements multi threading, parallel computing, common prime detection and an ram disk, but the initial idea was great, is fast :O

Comment: @JhetoXekri Since it's just obfuscated trial-division with a bad choice of divisors, there isn't anything great about it. No amount of parallel computing or tweaking will get it anywhere close to RSA key sizes.

Comment: Thinking on another thing if sqrt(N) is the middle for near primes, exist an way to get the limit for near primes ? thinking on values on (top/bottom) of sqrt(N) ?

Comment: @CodesInChaos why not can break ? an Amazon EC2 can break an 512 key, an botnet/mining pool can't break that ? http://arstechnica.com/security/2015/10/breaking-512-bit-rsa-with-amazon-ec2-is-a-cinch-so-why-all-the-weak-keys/

Comment: @JhetoXekri GNFS can break 512-bit keys at low cost and possibly 1024-bit keys if have a huge budget. This algorithm and anything similar to it couldn't even break a 256-bit key even if you used all the computers on earth.

Comment: @CodesInChaos thanks for the info.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the following pseudo code is intended:

```
function factor(bigint N) {
    bigint s = ceil(sqrt(N))
    while (gcd(N,s*s-1)==1) {
        s = s+1
    }
    return  factorpair(gcd(N,s*s-1), N/gcd(N,s*s-1))
}
```

This does not look like a serious method though: The gcd simply tests against common factors with $s+1$ and $s-1$; hence an immediate improvement consists in simply testing the $\gcd$ of $N$ with all the integers from $\lfloor\sqrt N\rfloor$ onward ...

Comment: My upvote for the comment.

Comment: thanks, just i testing, you show me, ways to fix that.

Comment: So it's just a trial-division strategy that fares about the same as testing $2..\sqrt n$ in the RSA case (Exactly two factors of similar size) and much worse in the general case (The interval from $2..\sqrt n$ is *much* shorter than the interval $\sqrt n .. n$).

Comment: ok thanks, i update the method, to search for bottom and top prime values, with this modification, i found more fast p, and at same time q, n=p*q, well i test that on 16bit key, and works, now the next step, is create an distributed/parallel pool for this factorization model, thinking on an bitcoin mining pool, this new model is really fast, is awesome.

Comment: Thinking on another thing if sqrt(N) is the middle for near primes, exist an way to get the limit for near primes ? thinking on values on (top/bottom) of sqrt(N) ?